# Pseudo-potential form factors for gold

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, elements, data

Can anyone suggest a reference in which I can find the Fourier coefficients of the pseudopotential of gold?

I cannot find them anywhere in literature.

I need them to compute the role of plasmon decay in the production of secondary electrons in gold as suggested in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.15.4699) for aluminum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand, the pseudopotential should be used in connection with the nearly free electron (NFE) approximation.

A preliminar warning is that, while NFE approximation works well with the alkali metals and reasonably well with most of the *s-p* bonded metallic systems, application to $d-$electrons metals somewhat transcends the reasonable limits of applicability of the theory.

Nevertheless, in the 70's a lot of work have been done to  derive good quality pseudopotentials that could be used in connection with NFE theory.

A possible reference is J. A. Moriarty, [*Pseudopotential Form Factors for Copper, Silver, and Gold*, Phys. Rev. B 1, 1363 (1970)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.1.1363).

The paper follows the generalization of pseudopotential method introduced by Harrison. In the paper, values of the pseudopotential form factors at densities of liquid and solid gold have been calculated.